# Use numpy and pandas, given the list we need to find all combinations that add upto 3

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Need all the combinations which add up to x.

```py
a = [1, +0, -6, 2, 3, 1, -0, 1, 2, -6, 9]
x = 3
```

Output: Eg.

```py
1,2
1,1,1
```

Comment: What do `+0` and `-0` mean here? Should they be included in your combinations, i.e., `[(1, 2), (1, 2, -0), (1, 2, +0), (1, 2, -0, +0), ...]`? And if so, is it OK to show them as `0` or do you need to preserve the sign? Also,  do the reported combinations need to preserve the order of the numbers in the original list? And should duplicate numbers be reported twice, e.g. all the combinations of the various 1's and 2's here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Numpy or Pandas would be particularly helpful for this, but here is a plain Python approach that should be pretty efficient. It doesn't preserve the order of the original numbers.

Note that this will only report the same combination once, even if there are multiple ways to make it (e.g., `(1, 2)`). This matches your example. It also treats `+0` and `-0` as `0`.

```
a = [1, +0, -6, 2, 3, 1, -0 , 1, 2, -6, 9] 
x = 3

def find_sums(lst, total):
    """
    Report all permutations of items in `lst` that add up to `total`.
    `lst` must be sorted.
    """
    print(f"called with {lst}, {total}")
    results = set()
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if v > total:
            # no more solutions possible; return what we have
            break
        elif v == total:
            # v will finish a series, but we don't stop in case there are 
            # zeroes later
            results.add((v,))
        else:
            # find all possible solutions starting with the current `v`
            results.update(
                  (v,) + c 
                  for c in find_sums(lst[(i+1):], total-v)
            )
    
    return results

print(find_sums(sorted(a), x))
# {
#   (-6, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
#   (-6, -6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 9), 
#   (-6, 0, 9), 
#   (-6, -6, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 9),
#   (-6, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
#   (0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
#   (-6, -6, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9), 
#   (0, 1, 2), 
#   (-6, 9), 
#   (-6, -6, 1, 2, 3, 9), 
#   (1, 2), 
#   (0, 0, 3), 
#   (-6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
#   (-6, 0, 0, 9), 
#   (-6, -6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 9), 
#   (3,), 
#   (-6, -6, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 9), 
#   (-6, -6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 9), 
#   (-6, -6, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 9), 
#   (0, 1, 1, 1), 
#   (0, 3), 
#   (0, 0, 1, 2), 
#   (-6, -6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9), 
#   (1, 1, 1)
# }
```